# Start Server (WebSphere) as a build step with buildah/podman to configure it

Tags: podman, buildah

In docker I can just boot the server (WebSphere) as a build step and start configuring it via it's jython SOAP API.

I'm trying convert my Dockerfile into a shell script using buildah to create the container instead of docker build. Is there an easy way to achieve this same behaviour? (It's not working so far)

Things I tried so far:

- buildah run $container /opt/../startServer.sh server1

  result:
  `timeout`
- chroot $mountpoint bash -c "/opt/../startServer.sh server1"

  result:
  `error: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director`

edit 1:

- Also tried running `buildah build-using-dockerfile` with a working Dockerfile when using docker itself but it fails with buildah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found out it to be a port conflict causing the server not to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try podman run.

Buildah run is not the same thing as `docker run`, `podman run` is.

Buildah run works like the RUN command in a Dockerfile.

Comment: I already tried `buildah run $container /opt/../startServer.sh server1` but the server never boots, it times out. It seem to behave differently then RUN in a Dockerfile.